# Conditionally adding body class and then filtering via PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm adding a body class to my page based on browser support for the Google Speech API. The idea is to then check for that class and serve the appropriate search form based on browser support.

Javascript/Jquery is inlined in the document head:

```
$.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(function() {
      if (Modernizr.speechrecognition) {
        $("body").addClass("voice-searchable");
      }
    });
  });
```

Checking the page source, I can see that the class `voice-searchable` is being added in the appropriate browsers.

PHP:

```
add_filter( 'genesis_search_form', 'my_search_form', 10, 4);
function my_search_form( $form ) {
  $classes = get_body_class();
  if (in_array('voice-searchable',$classes)) {
  // NEXT 2 LINES FOR DEBUGGING
    print_r ($classes);
    print (' FUBAR');
    $form = 'CODE FOR VOICE SEARCH FORM HERE';
  } else {
  // NEXT 2 LINES FOR DEBUGGING
    print_r ($classes);
    print (' BARFOO');
      $form = 'CODE FOR TEXT ONLY FORM HERE';
  }
  return $form;
}
```

And finally this in my `speech-input.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(function () {
    if (Modernizr.speechrecognition) {
      $("body").addClass("voice-searchable");
    }
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/wp-content/themes/my-child-theme/include/search.php",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false,
      data: {
        'action': 'my_search_ajax_request',
      },
      success: function (data) {
        //If the success function is execute,
        //then the Ajax request was successful.
        //Add the data we received in our Ajax
        //request to the "breadcrumb_search" div.
        $(".breadcrumb_search").html(data);
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        var errorMsg = "Ajax request failed: " + xhr.responseText;
        $(".breadcrumb_search").html(errorMsg);
      }

    });
  });
});
(window, jQuery, window.Window_Ready);
```

Despite the existence of the desired body class, the 2nd form is being returned, and the printed array of body classes does not include `voice-searchable`. I've tried changing the priority from `10`to a higher number, but without success.

Why does the PHP filter not parse the added body class? How can I get it to see it? Do I need to wrap it in a function that fires later?

Thanks for looking.

EDIT:

@loganbertram Thank you. I'm totally new to using Ajax, but I tried this:

```
/*
 * Ajax for speech recognition; place in functions.php
 */

function my_search_ajax_enqueue() {
  // Enqueue javascript on the frontend.
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'my-search-ajax-script',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/speech-input.js',
    array('jquery')
  );
  // The wp_localize_script allows us to output the ajax_url path for our script to use.
  wp_localize_script(
    'my-search-ajax-script',
    'my_search_ajax_obj',
    array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) )
  );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_search_ajax_enqueue' );
```

plus this (in search.php):

```
function my_search_ajax_request() {
  add_filter( 'genesis_search_form', 'my_search_form', 99, 4);
  function my_search_form( $form ) {
    $classes = get_body_class();
    if (in_array('voice-searchable',$classes)) {
      $form = 'CODE FOR FORM HERE';
    } else {
      $form = 'CODE FOR TEXT ONLY FORM HERE';
    }
    return $form;
  }
  die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_search_ajax_request', 'my_search_ajax_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_search_ajax_request', 'my_search_ajax_request' );
```

And finally, this in `speech-input.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(function () {
    if (Modernizr.speechrecognition) {
      $("body").addClass("voice-searchable");
    }
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/wp-content/themes/child-theme-name/include/search.php",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false,
      data: {
        'action': 'my_search_ajax_request',
      },
      success: function (data) {
        //If the success function is execute,
        //then the Ajax request was successful.
        //Add the data we received in our Ajax
        //request to the "breadcrumb_search" div.
        $(".breadcrumb_search").html(data);
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        var errorMsg = "Ajax request failed: " + xhr.responseText;
        $(".breadcrumb_search").html(errorMsg);
      }

    });
  });
});
(window, jQuery, window.Window_Ready);
```

Which gives a 500 error & displays the error message. Obviously not the right syntax. Most of the examples I could find were for retrieving data from variables or getting form values, nothing so simple as just rendering some HTML from a PHP file. If anyone out there could point me to an example of how to do the latter, I'd appreciate it.

EDIT: I solved the AJAX question & will post the answer in a separate topic.

Comment: PHP is server-side and fires first.  Then the browser receives it and processes the JS adding the class.  In short, when the PHP runs to render the page, the target class hasn't been added.  You could after changing class add an ajax request to the salient bits of the PHP instead.

Comment: Thank you; if you'll post this as an answer I'll accept it as correct.

Comment: Great, will do.  I wasn't entirely convinced that it was at the level of an answer, but I'm glad to have helped.

Comment: It answered the question. How to solve the problem was a different bag of cats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is server-side and fires first. Then the browser receives it and processes the JS adding the class. In short, when the PHP runs to render the page, the target class hasn't been added. You could after changing class add an ajax request to the salient bits of the PHP instead.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code to your functions.php then check

Please remove all js that your are using for add class to body .

```
add_filter( 'body_class','my_body_classes' );
function my_body_classes( $classes ) {

    $classes[] = 'voice-searchable';

    return $classes;

}
```

Comment: I'm using Modernizr.js to check for browser feature support, so that's a no-go.